# USB 3.0 via Firewire

Tags: usb, firewire

I saw a usb to firewire cable ([http://www.amazon.com/Firewire-Ieee-Ilink-Adapter-Cable/product-reviews/B0049DJ0JG/ref=cm_cr_pr_btm_link_4?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1&sortBy=recent&reviewerType=all_reviews&filterByStar=all_stars&pageNumber=4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0049DJ0JG)) and I was wondering if I can hookup my USB 3.0 flash disk to firewire port on PC. What drivers would be involved? Any benchmarking info much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/540482/is-there-any-usb-3-0-to-firewire-800-1394b-adapter?rq=1 and http://superuser.com/questions/306437/converting-firewire-to-usb-3-is-it-theoretically-possible?rq=1

Comment: Did you read the reviews on the Amazon link?

Answer (score 1):

The reviews suggest no, you can't do that, and its just a way to charge a firewire device over USB.

Practically speaking, even if they have the same number of pins, the electrical and data protocols are distinct enough that you'd need some flavour of active device to do it.

Benchmarking info would be simple. Assuming you don't accidentally blow anything up, 0.